# jQuery accordion not working on IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

jQuery accordion not working on IE. 
In IE the accordion all are in open state.

But its work perfect in Firefox.

Why accordion is visible all time in expand state, no chance to collapsed ?
how to solve the issues ?

Comment: @dhrubyoti post your code pleaase

Answer (score 0):

At least on IE8 (probably on IE7 too) you can use "Developer tools", activating the debugging, to catch errors dynamically in your web pages on IE.